# ASP.net 5.0 - WebAPI Authorize & ErrorCode 302 instead of 401

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ASP.net 5.0 (MVC 6) Website and use this website also for some mobile apps. I  have a controller that returns json data.

The User has to Authenticate to see this data so I use the [Authorize] attribute for the Controller.

I expected to get an Error 401 for not authorized requests nur I get an redirect (302) to the loginpage. 
In the Mobile Client a set the header to only accept "application/json" data but I still get the redirect to the login page.

I developed an solution that works but I'm not very happy with it. It works but it is a kind of hack.

Is there a better solution to handle this?

Here my solution (Configure method in Startup class)

```
        //....Some Code
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next.Invoke();

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 302)
            {
                StringValues contentType;
                if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Accept", out contentType)
                    && contentType.Contains("application/json"))
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    if (env.IsDevelopment())
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("No Access");
                }
            }
        });
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: According to https://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/147201-asp-net-web-api/suggestions/2856315-add-option-to-return-401-not-authorized-instead-of , it's fixed

Answer (score 4):

This should be solved by the client. The client have to send a `X-Requested-With` header with the value `XMLHttpRequest`.

So this should be a part of the headers section in the HTTP request:

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Now you'll get your 401's without hacks.

Comment: This does not work with dotnet core, you must add a custom event to your authentication middleware (e.g. CookieAuthenticationMiddleware or OpenIdConnectMiddleware) to detect the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header and return a 401 yourself.

Comment: Perfect. That's what I was looking for. Thanks.